# How to tell UI5 to run PC version?

Tags: sapui5

UI5 handles PC and mobile layout differently. My app has some specific components that not work well on mobile, like not working at all. However the PC version works just fine.

So I wonder if there is a way to force/tell UI5 which library/platform to run exactly (no device adaptation)? Thank you.

I tried to set `phone:false` or delete it in `manifest.json` but it didn't work.

Comment: If you have same layout for both PC and Mobile you can use the same set of code. You can achieve by using `sap.m` controls.

Comment: UI5 is fully responsive provided you use libraries which support both mobile and desktop. I advise you only use those libraries (and so does SAP).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its completely depend on your application layout and the way of coding. If the application have same layout for both PC and Mobile then you can achieve it by using `sap.m` library which provide responsiveness.

UI5 also provides some [Device specific APIs](https://help.sap.com/viewer/0ce0b8c56fa74dd897fffda8407e8272/7.5.9/en-US/69a8e469fbde46e7b8916250080effbd.html) you can use them as well. Also there is a [jQuery APIs](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/jQuery) with helps to check device type but it is **depreciated** instead you can use [Device APIs](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.Device).

If you have a different layouts then create a root view in `component.js`

```
// create root view
var oView = sap.ui.view({
    id: "app",
    viewName: "ABC.custom.App",
    type: "JS",
    viewData: { component: this },
});
```

Now inside the Root app view you can check and load the corresponding Mobile or Desktop initial views.

```
if (sap.ui.Device.system.phone)
   app.addPage(sap.ui.jsview("mMileageListing", "ABC.custom.mobile.mMain"));
else
   app.addPage(sap.ui.jsview("dMileageListing", "ABC.custom.desktop.dMain"));
```

Comment: It's not a real different in layout between PC and mobile, but you gave me an idea to have corresponding mobile and PC views. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If its only a component I would hide it in your XML View:

```
visible="{= ${device>/system/phone} ? 'false' : 'true'}"
```

If you dont have `${device>/system/phone}` check the WEB IDE templates how to achieve this.
Thats a view model called device, containing the system information.

Maybe also for JavaScript in a controller where device is of type `sap/ui/Device`

Definition

```
sap.ui.define([
        "..../BaseController",
        "sap/ui/Device"
    ], function (BaseController, Device) {
        "use strict";
```

Code:

```
 var bIsPhone = !Device.system.phone;
```